# multiple d3 collapsible tree layouts sharing a node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I want to draw two d3 (collapsible) tree layouts that share a common node, e.g. the root. In my first attempt ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epantaleo/x6670vzo/)) , when I click on one of the nodes of one of the collapsible trees, the tree translates to accommodate the new nodes and therefore the root nodes do not overlap anymore. How can I anchor the position of the two roots so that they move together whenever one of them translates?

A dirty way of doing this would be to create a `centerNode(node)` function that centers a `node` in the middle of the screen and then to apply the `centerNode` function to both roots (`root` and `root2`). Below I'm posting part of the code you can find in the jsfiddle:

```
var root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

var root2 = treeData2[0];
root2.x0 = height / 2;
root2.y0 = 0;
collapse(root);
root2.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root2, tree2, root2, -500., -1, "nodeD", "linkD", j);
update(root, tree, root, -500, 1, "nodeA", "linkA", i);

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d, source, mytree, myroot, position, symmetry, myclass, mylinks, ii) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d, source, mytree, myroot, position, symmetry, myclass, mylinks, ii);
  //centerNode(root);
  //centerNode(root2);
}
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is not working. I'm working on something similar. I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @SoorajChandran, I found this http://bl.ocks.org/jdarling/2d4e84460d5f5df9c0ff which has exactly what I was looking for although collapsing doesn't work any more. How do you think your work is related to this? It would be interesting to exchange ideas.